# The canvas has been tainted by cross-origin data

Tags: javascript, apache

Problem

- i have Reffred Link :https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/CORS_enabled_image.
- https://github.com/h5bp/server-configs-apache/blob/fc379c45f52a09dd41279dbf4e60ae281110a5b0/src/.htaccess#L36-L53

/etc/apache2/apache2.conf

```
 <Directory /var/www/html>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
     <IfModule mod_setenvif.c>
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    <FilesMatch "\.(cur|gif|ico|jpe?g|png|svgz?|webp)$">
        SetEnvIf Origin ":" IS_CORS
        Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*" env=IS_CORS
    </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
</IfModule>
  </Directory>
```

- start the apache again .

Bug:

```
   Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to execute 'getImageData' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The canvas has been tainted by cross-origin data.
```

Code

```
        var image = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height),//debugger breakpoint stop here.
        imageData = image.data;
```

Debug solution

- i have googled and find that no browser will allow cross origin images.
- i don"t need to save images of cross origin .
- change in .htaccess file.
- how to debug the issue.

Comment: What have you changed in `.htaccess`? Is the space in between `</If   Module>` really exist?  Can you show you canvas render codes (related part)?

Comment: i have used code mozilla  <IfModule mod_setenvif.c>
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
        <FilesMatch "\.(cur|gif|ico|jpe?g|png|svgz?|webp)$">
            SetEnvIf Origin ":" IS_CORS
            Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*" env=IS_CORS
        </FilesMatch>
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>

Comment: what is error is im doing any silly raptor

Comment: Did you add the `crossorigin` attribute to your image? I think you can use `crossorigin="anonymous"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Along with the headers, I think you need to add the `crossorigin` attribute to your image tag.

Example image tag:

```
<img src="www.domain.com/image.jpg" crossorigin="anonymous" />
```

If you are doing this via javascript, here is the code example in the Mozilla link you provided:

```
var img = new Image,
    canvas = document.createElement("canvas"),
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d"),
    src = "http://example.com/image"; // insert image url here

// Notice that they set the cross origin attribute here
img.crossOrigin = "Anonymous";
```

Here is  elevant passage from the docs (Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/CORS_enabled_image):

> The HTML specification introduces a crossorigin attribute for images
>   that, in combination with an appropriate CORS header, allows images
>   defined by the  element loaded from foreign origins to be used in
>   canvas as if they were being loaded from the current origin.

And also this passage may be helpful from this page (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/CORS_settings_attributes):

> By default (that is, when the attribute is not specified), CORS is not
>   used at all. The "anonymous" keyword means that there will be no
>   exchange of user credentials via cookies, client-side SSL certificates
>   or HTTP authentication as described in the Terminology section of the
>   CORS specification.

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'width' of null error im reciving

Comment: canvas.width = img.width;  js:31 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'width' of null

Comment: Probably image has not been loaded yet. May need to use `onload` event before trying to get width. Here is possibly helpful link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/623172/how-to-get-image-size-height-width-using-javascript